# Ms SQL Procedure running slow

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, optimization

```
DECLARE @userId INT = 1001

SELECT 
    , Logins.IP
    , COUNT(LoginsOther.UserId) AS OtherUsersOnThisIp
    , MAX(Logins.DateHappened) AS LastUsed
    , Logins.UserId
FROM Security.UserLogin AS Logins 
LEFT JOIN Security.UserLogin AS LoginsOther 
  ON LoginsOther.IP = Logins.IP 
 AND LoginsOther.UserId <> Logins.UserId 
WHERE Logins.UserId = @userId
GROUP BY 
    , Logins.IP
    , Logins.UserId
```

So, I have Table UserLogin with columns: `Id int, DateHappened datetime, IP nvarchar, LoginStatusId int, UserId bigint`
there are 17769 records in this table.
The task is to take used IP adresses by user and `OtherUsersOnThisIp` must show other user count used this IpAddress, when I run query Result count is 22 rows but it takes 10-19 seconds. 
Are there any ways to optimize this query run faster?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on tables?

Comment: no I have not indexes

Comment: So there is your answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP does not even know how to use indexes when query tuning. He needs a tutorial. He will not be able to understand answers.

Comment: create nonunique index IX_UserLogin_User on Security.UserLogin(UserId,IP);
create nonunique index IX_UserLogin_IP on Security.UserLogin(IP,UserId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such is the nature of <> queries, they are relatively slower. Since you are using a stored procedure, you may not be constrained to write it a single query. You could use a temporary table to get a smaller list of IPs for a specific user ID, a not-equal-to query on a smaller table may be more efficient than one that is used in-line, with, of all things in a left join.